# Submitting the Apple Watch app

Tags: xcode, ios8, watchkit

I am trying to submit an iOS App + Apple watch extension to the App Store.

1. I selected the app as my target, created an archive (Product > Archive).
2. I clicked on the archive in Window > Organizer and clicked Export (I am using the Application loader to submit the app).
3. I selected "Save for iOS App Store Deployment"
4. In the next window (in Binary and Entitlements), I expected to see the the app and the watchkit extension. But I see only the app. Why is this ? Is it expected ? Or did I miss some setting change somewhere ?

Answer (score 2):

Because this is a very special piece of application, and you can not just simply submit the application like the way you used to do.

The differences are the total number of provisioning profile. Without **WatchKitExtension**, a provisioning profile is enough. However, you have to apply for three different application identifiers and three different provisioning profile in order to let the **Xcode** to detect you actually have your phone app, watch app and watch extension.

So, what you need to do is really simple. Just create two more app identifiers based on the bundle identifier you saw from the **WatchApp** target and **WatchExtension** target. Then, create two more provisioning profile. Last step, import them into your **Xcode**. And you are good to go.