# How to upload application with app groups to Apple store?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit, ios-app-group

I create an app with Watchkit extension using App Groups function. Now I want to upload this app to Apple store. I do like this:

- Create App ID for my App (ex:com.standardApplication.tictactoe)
- Enable appGroup in Capabilities in Xcode for IOS app and Watchkit app using identifier: "group.com.standardApplication.ticTacToe"
  [image]
- Create Provisioning Profiles for Development and Distribution on Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles center with my App ID that I create before. Download it and double klick to add it to my Xcode.
  [image][image]
- After that I go to Itune connect to make a new App with my App ID and info...
- After that in Xcode and build Setting, I changed the code signing for all targets(iOS Target and Watchkit target) like this:
  [image]

But when I tried to archive my app for submit to Apple Store I got this error:

```
Check dependencies

Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: com.apple.security.application-groups.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'WatchKit Extension' in SDK 'iOS 8.3'
```

I don't know how to fix that, although I tried some method that I know or search google but no luck, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a also create WatchKit Extension provisioning profiles & create and set the same way to your ios app.

- create Extension app id (ex:com.standardApplication.tictactoe.watchkitApp)
- Enable appGroup Capabilities in Extension app id and set Extension
      app target
- Create Provisioning Profiles for Extension app and then set..

Comment: It's not just a simple provisioning profile. You need to create two more provisioning profiles for the watch kit extension and the watch app. So, it should be total three provisioning profile for submitting the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this question on this post, you can probably check this out:
[Submitting the Apple Watch app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020461/submitting-the-apple-watch-app/30020760#30020760)

That's the content here:

> Because this is a very special piece of application, and you can not
>   just simply submit the application like the way you used to do.
>
> The differences are the total number of provisioning profile. Without
>   WatchKitExtension, a provisioning profile is enough. However, you have
>   to apply for three different application identifiers and three
>   different provisioning profile in order to let the Xcode to detect you
>   actually have your phone app, watch app and watch extension.
>
> So, what you need to do is really simple. Just create two more app
>   identifiers based on the bundle identifier you saw from the WatchApp
>   target and WatchExtension target. Then, create two more provisioning
>   profile. Last step, import them into your Xcode. And you are good to
>   go.