# code sign error when migrating from watchKit 1 to 2

Tags: xcode, watchkit, code-signing, watchos-2

I got this error when attempt to update watchKit 1 app to 2. The watchKit 1 app works fine in Xcode 6.

```
Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: com.apple.security.application-groups.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'WatchKit Extension' in SDK 'Watch OS 2.0'
```

Where can I find more information about these?

Comment: I think so, but not sure about the steps. Think I find the entitlement and delete it.

Comment: Yeah, this is what worked for me too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload application with app groups to Apple store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022915/how-to-upload-application-with-app-groups-to-apple-store)